# Sentence ending with a number and an exclamation point

Tags: notation

Suppose you want to emphasize some idea and your sentence ends with a number. You want to be clear to the reader that you do not mean factorial. For instance, you wish to emphasize

> When using method $ABC$, your approximation is off by a factor of 3.

Would it be appropriate (and, more importantly, *clear to the reader*) to say the following?

> When using method $ABC$, your approximation is off by a factor of 3!

I understand for this example, you could easily change "3" to "three", as in:

> When using method $ABC$, your approximation is off by a factor of three!

However, this last idea would not be not pleasant for the following sentence:

> When using method $ABC$, your approximation is off by a factor of $\sqrt{3}$!

Is there an accepted and common way to write these exclamation points, other than rewriting the sentence to avoid ending with a number?

Comment: Everything should be clear from the context. If a factorial really was intended an extra punctuation mark would be in order.

Comment: Maybe you should try to ask your question here:
https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Travis That was explicitly not allowed here, to encourage other methods.

Comment: If this is handwritten communication you could underline for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is the *end* of the sentence, there needs to be a period after the exclamation point, if factorial was meant.  So the lack of a period would be a clear signal to the reader that the exclamation point is punctuation and not math.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting the sentence, you can try to rewrite the number, where appropriate. For example, instead of writing "$\pi + 3!$", you can write "$3 + \pi!$". This decreases the likelihood of a confusion.